# Xamarin - Problem installing 13.16.0.13 on MAC

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

On my Windows 10 PC (Visual Studio 2019 - 16.5.3)  when I open my Xamarin project it automatically connects to my MAC.  But I get the following  error:

```
    Xamarin.iOS.versions mismatch
        The Xamarin.iOS SDK version '13.16.0.11' that is installed on the Mac is not compatible with this version of Visual Studio.
Would you like us to install Xamarin.iOS '13.16.0.13' for you? This will overwrite any other existing Xamarin.iOS installation on your Mac.
```

When I click Install (sometimes) it gets as far as 1% downloaded but then I always get the error:

```
    Xamarin.iOS.versions mismatch
            There were problems installing Xamarin.iOS from: 
'https://aka.ms/xvs/pkg/macios/13.16.0.13'. 
Please try again and if the problem persists, try installing directly on the Mac and connect again
```

I have tried top go to the URL on my MAC to install directly, but the URL does not exist?!!?

Also if I look at Help/About Visual Studio, it lists:
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   13.16.0.13 (b75deaf).

Incidentally, I can still Debug/Release on the iPhone connected to the MAC, but not on any of the iOS emulators on the PC??

How can I manually install 13.16.0.13 on the MAC?

Has anyone any ideas as to what the issue may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I always do now, is download the file (from the given URL) on my PC, then copy it across to the MAC and install it.  Not sure why the MAC won't download it.  I'm sure this isn't really the answer, but it works every time for me.

Comment: Incidentally, as of Xamarin Forms 4.8.0.1.1269  This started working automatically again.  Up until that version, I had to do the above.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried top go to the URL on my MAC to install directly, but the
>   URL does not exist?!!?

The url is correct and I think maybe you have a typo,it is:

https://aka.ms/xvs/pkg/macios/13.16.0.13

Type it directly in the browser and it will download Xamarin.iOS 13.16.0.13 automatically.

Another way is if you have Visual-Studio in your Mac, you can update your Visual-Studio to the latest version.

Comment: weird.  if i type it in on the MAC i end up at https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/?ref=aka.  If I go to my mac, open browser and click on your link it downloads.  I cannot explain.  But thanks, downloading now.

Comment: Jack Hua - MSFT   Have you actually managed to download it?  It gets to 203MB on mine, then just stops.  My connection is tine.

Comment: @RobL Yes, I just test and I can download it on my side.

Comment: Crazy.  Downloaded it on PC. USB'd it over to the MAC, installed fine.  All good now.  Obviously, a totally unrelated issue.  Thanks Hack.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT There is an issue with the server. Now on probably the 6th download attempt, and download halts/fails after a certain period.

Answer (score 0):

Recently having the same problem. This is exacerbated by the slow server speed. While I have a 50Mb/s download speed, it's taking 10mins just to get the above package to 3% download.

I did manage to get the file downloading and installed, after having repeatedly deleted `hosts.key` from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\MonoTouch`

Unfortunately I then got an error saying "problem with broker". After updating Visual Studio 2019 to latest, it now wants to download Xamarin.ios all over again, but the main issue is the download speed, and once more the file stopped downloading at 600Mb (out of 800). Local connection is fine.

So in short, the VS version earlier than the one current for today had issues. But while the latest version probably works, the server is degraded, download speed poor, and connection randomly halts.

Comment: Happened again for me.  Won't download on a Mac.  Have to do it on a PC and then copy it over.

Comment: @RobL I think it's just a flakey server. I got it down after about 7 download attempts and 2 days of wasted time.

Comment: Works every time if I download it to my PC, then USB it over to the Mac and install.  Weird.